# Pattern help Java

Tags: java

I'm completely lost on how i would go about making a java program
that does this.
Could explain to me how I would go about doing this?

> What pattern do you want me to draw: 4
>
> What size do you want this pattern: 23

```
                      *
                    *
                  *
                *
              *
            *
          *
        *
      *               *
    *                 *
  *                   *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
                      *
```

Comment: Only Simple way I can think of is a sea of println statements..

Comment: SO is not a place for asking others do your homework.

Comment: I was just asking how i would go about doing this. because the user needs to input what letter or number they want replicated and a size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure, your teacher will be happy:

```
    boolean[][] f = new boolean[24][15];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        f[12 - i][i] = f[12][i] = f[9 + i][11] = f[12][14 - i] = f[23-i][11] = true;

    for (boolean[] r : f) {
        for (boolean b : r) {
            System.out.print(b ? "* " : "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```